# How to make this bot work?

Tags: python, flash, bots

I got a bot in Python that I've made to simulate a player playing a flash web game. The thing is, I've used an approach that requires specific screen coordinates to work, and there is a pop-up I need to click to advance to the next state that seems to appear in random positions every time it shows up.

Do you know how to "detect" where the popup is?.

Thanks.

Comment: Computer Vision and On-Screen Recognition. `OpenCV` should do the trick here I think.

Comment: pywinauto will let you click the popup pretty easy

Answer (score 1):

I'd try saving the button you have to click as a pic, then scan your entire screen and use PIL to match the pic you saved to the button you have to press; from there you should be able to retrieve the coordinates.

Comment: But what if the button style change a little?, can I somehow recognize the text that is displayed in it?, for example the phrase: "save now" or something like that.